# Disadvantage of building a custom element within the constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, html-templates

I understand the advantages of templates in terms of performance when designing custom elements, but for structures which are only used in one element I am struggling to understand the disadvantage of building the html within the `constructor()` of the element class definition itself.

Put another way, what is the disadvantage of doing something like this:

```
const myTemplate = document.createElement("template");
myTemplate.innerHTML = `<p>my text</p>`;

customElements.define( 'my-elem', class extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(myTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

})
```

over this:

```
customElements.define( 'my-elem', class extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();

    let myP = document.createElement("p");
    let myText = document.createTextNode("my text");
    myP.appendChild(myText);

    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(myP);
  }

})
```

... when the latter option both (a) preserves the advantages of using `createElement`, and (b) helps prevent potential encapsulation issues introduced by defining the template outside the scope of the element definition?

I'm also aware that I could build the template with `createElement` instead of `innerHTML` in the example above, but that has the potential to introduce even more variables defined outside the scope of the element definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subtle difference and boils down to requirements and/or team/personal preference.

I would do:

```js
customElements.define( 'my-elem', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    let myP = document.createElement("p");
    let myText = document.createTextNode("my text");
    myP.append(myText);
    // MDN docs are wrong, you can put code *before* super
    super() // create and return 'this'
         // create and return this.shadowRoot
        .attachShadow({ mode: "open" }) 
        .append(myP);
  }
})
customElements.define( 'my-elem2', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
        .attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
        .innerHTML = "Hello! Component";
  }
})
```

```html
<my-elem></my-elem>
<my-elem2></my-elem2>
```

Comment: `MDN docs are wrong, you can put code *before* super`: yeah, you're right! I think it's just a best practice, not a requirement.

Comment: What MDN means/should say is: _You can't reference the 'this' scope before it is created by the super() call_